# Comparing monocular SLAM path to ground truth

Tags: compare, computer-vision, slam-algorithm

I have created a dataset with a very accurate ground truth in 6DoF (both position and attitude) and would like to use this to compare the accuracy of the path in 6DoF for different monocular SLAM algorithms.

The ground truth results in a path in 6DoF relative to the ground truth's coordinate frame. The SLAM algorithms results in a path in 6DoF relative to the SLAM's coordinate frame

Due to the nature of monocular SLAM algorithms, I do not have a scale of the path.

How can I solve this with my dataset? Is there any available scripts?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I posted this on ROS forums, however I thought it would be nice to post here instead as.
1. I think it would be of interest outside the ROS community
2. ROS is a slow forum

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is find a transform between local and global coordinates. Depending on your exact state model the equations will change. But the basic idea is to start off with a known point in both frames. Say at initial time in our Global frame we have (**P**osition **g**lobal) `Pg=[xg0 yg0 zg0 rg0 pg0 yg0]` and the robots coordinate is `Pr =[xr0 yr0 zr0 rr0 pr0 yr0]` at this point we need create the mapping from Pg to Pr Once we have this we can represent all data in the same.

Mapping from 6dof to another 6dof is very difficult and highly nonlinear. It can usually be thought of in two steps

1. map between xyz to get the axis in the same area.
2. map the orientations between the two  axis (roll, pitch yaw)

I couldn't find many sources on doing both simultaneously, but if you do them sequentially it will still work (order matters so be consistent) here is a nice post that has xyz transforms https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79765/how-do-i-convert-from-the-global-coordinate-space-to-a-local-space

this website is great (I used it for a 3d SLAM problem, it was incredibly helpful) and it has information on roll pitch yaw transforms. http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node104.html if you explore the website you should also find xyz transforms. Sometimes it helsp to start off with the 2D examples first so you understand the concept then look at the 3D after

Good luck

**edit**

I originally posted the wrong link to the planning website but its fixed. Here is the main equation [image]

Your landmark points for SLAM  are the output of this equation `Global landmark = T * Landmark w/respect Robot` and each point is represented as `[x,y,z,1]` the 1 is needed to preserve translation. The roll(alpha) pitch(beta) and yaw(gamma) are obtained from the rotation matrix between the Global coordinates and the robots coordinates